# kendo autocompletion issue

Tags: php, kendo-ui

I'm dealing with kendo autocomplete. But it's not working properly. I don't understand what the problem is. Here is my code. Please help me out to solve this.

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
   minLength : 1,
       dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
       serverFiltering: true,
       dataType: "json",
           transport: {
               read:  {
                        url: "data/emp_det.php",
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                return {
                                    StartsWith: options.filter.filters[0].value
                                }
                            }
               },
           },
           schema: {
               data: "data"
           },

   }),
   dataTextField: "user_name",
     });

})(jQuery, kendo);
```

my php file is

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=abc', 'root', '');
    $arr = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, user_name FROM employee WHERE user_name LIKE ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET["StartsWith"]. "%"))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr[] = $row;    
    }
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`parameterMap` is an object of `transport` and not from `read`, documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap).

It should be:

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength : 1,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        dataType: "json",
        transport: {
            read:  {
                url: "data/emp_det.php"
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                return {
                    StartsWith: options.filter.filters[0].value
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data"
        }
    }),
    dataTextField: "user_name"
});
```